# Cannot find module 'mongoose'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bson

I am currently doing a project with mongodb and node.js, but I have met this issue after I install mongoose.

1 first I use npm install mongoose to install the latest version@5.7.5

2 [then I get this issue Cannot find module ‘mongoose’](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpy3V.jpg)

3  and I am sure mongoose is inside package-lock.json

4 I thought maybe I can try an early version of mongoose

5 [I install mongoose@5.7.3 then I got another issue, cannot find mongodb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWyZA.jpg)

6 [But MongoDB is inside package-lock.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m67VY.jpg)

7 [So I install mongodb again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5Msb.jpg)

8 [another issue, cannot find bson, which is also inside package-lock.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6EQ1.jpg)

9 [then I install bson again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kADVj.jpg)

10 [And I meet this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7oUn.jpg)

ok, after trying so many times... I don't know what to do now.. an anyone helps me?
my server.js is 
[server.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NZUA.jpg)

Comment: do you run npm install commands within your main project folder?

Comment: yes, and I use lcoal install : npm install mongoose, and the issue still exists..

Comment: Very likely you have a messed up setup. Try `npm list | grep mongoose` and `npm list -g | grep mongoose`. What's the output of both commands?

Comment: HI, Kevinadi, I have tried your suggest, the output is +-- mongoose@5.7.1 | +-- mongoose-legacy-pluralize@1.0.2 . I also tried to creat a new backend folder and use nodejs ,express and mongoose, the result was still the same, I am now douting its the problem of mongoose...